# Cannot connect to mongodb with strapi

Tags: node.js, mongodb, strapi

```
PS C:\Users\mihir\Desktop\node leraning\strapi_practice> npx create-strapi-app first
npx: installed 92 in 92.729s
Creating a new Strapi application at C:\Users\mihir\Desktop\node leraning\strapi_practice\first.

? Choose your installation type 
? Choose your installation type Custom (manual settings)
? Choose your default database client 
? Choose your default database client mongo
? Database name: learn
? Database name: learn
? Host: cluster_link {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}
? Host: cluster_link {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}
? +srv connection: (false) true
? +srv connection: true
? Port (It will be ignored if you enable +srv): (27017)
? Port (It will be ignored if you enable +srv): 27017
? Username: mihir
? Username: mihir
? Password: ****************
? Password: ****************
? Authentication database (Maybe "admin" or blank):
? Authentication database (Maybe "admin" or blank):
? Enable SSL connection: (y/N) y
? Enable SSL connection: Yes
⛔️ Connection test failed: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\mihir\AppData\Local\Temp\strapiff50605eed47\node_modules\strapi-connector-mongoose\node_modules\.bin'
```

I wrote a command to create a new strapi app with custom settings.I answered the custom setting questions in above manner.When i choose database as mongo I also passed {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}.But at last it is showing connection test failed.So i am unable to connect with my mongo.Please suggest some solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think that You should start mongodb first then start with installation